# Hot reload is not working in a specific file - Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I am working on a flutter project using android studio, everything works fine except that hot reload (Ctrl + S) doesn't work in a **specific file** showing "Reload not performed, Analysis issues found" although there are **no errors** in this file in dart analysis!

I tried:

- Invalidate caches / Restart
- Stop and run again

But both don't work, what should I do?

Comment: hot reload suppose will relaod the whole project, not just specific file.

Comment: @JohnJoe I know but I can't hot reload while in this file specifically

Comment: did u ever fix this?

Comment: @Abbas.M no, I actually left the project and the whole company

Comment: Okay i'll do that too thanks!